# Adding a home button to your wpf browser

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I can't seem to get the Home button in my wpf web browser to work. Do you guys have any idea?

I have tried:

```
WebBrowser1.GoHome();
```

But I'm reciving:

```
'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'GoHome' and no        extension method 'GoHome' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However, other commands are working just fine, for example:

```
WebBrowser1.GoBack();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign a set URL to the button/save the location as a file. Consider it more like a bookmark:

```
string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please set your home page", "Settings");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", "Start Page", "").ToString());
```

That will work for IE, for any other browser it gets...complicated...